# Find the sum of a list in Scala

Tags: scala

If I have a list of strings and I know the numeric vlaue of each string in the list how do i get the sum of the list?

Example:

I know:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5
```

I am given the following list:

```
List("a","b","d")
```

what the best way of calculating the sum 7?

Thanks

Comment: You want a function that accepts a list of keys and returns their sums, like a `Map[String, Int]` ? You didn't provide enough information.. Can strings in the list repeat more than once?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of creating a Map[String,Int] then doing .foldLeft(0)(_+_.2) but it's the conversion from the list into the map i'm having difficulties with. Yes the strings can repeat more than once. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val a = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5)

val b = List("a", "b", "d")

b.map(a.getOrElse(_, 0)).sum
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks!

Comment: You can also do `Map().withDefaultValue(0)` and then `b.map(a).sum`. Much cleaner xD

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the values are the same as the element position, then you can avoid a map:

```
object test {
  val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

  def sumThem = (for((letter, value) <- list.zipWithIndex) yield(value + 1)).sum
}

scala> test.sumThem
res2: Int = 15
```

Comment: Well... If you know the values are the same as the element position you can also ask Gauss: `(list.size * (list.size + 1))/2` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're 100% sure it's only letters

```
List("a","b","d").foldLeft(0)(_ + _.hashCode - 96)
```

if not, you can map it before

```
val letters = (1 to 26).map(x => Character.toString((x+96).toChar) -> x).toMap
```

and use @sheunis's answer:

```
val input = List("a","b","d")
input.map(letters.getOrElse(_, 0)).sum
```